# double calls ajax using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**two calls:**

```
$('#add').live('click', function() {

    $('.simplebox').slideUp(200, function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:140}, 350, function() {
            $('#loading-add').slideDown(300, function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "..",
                    data: getDataToPost(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){

                        alert(data);

                        $('#loading-add').delay(1000).fadeOut(200, function() {
                            $('#successfull-add').fadeIn(200);
                        });

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

})
```

But if i call to the ajax immediately after the `live` event, it calls on time (as it should be):

```
$('#add').live('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "..",
                    data: getDataToPost(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){

                        alert(data);

                        $('#loading-add').delay(1000).fadeOut(200, function() {
                            $('#successfull-add').fadeIn(200);
                        });

                    }
                });
})
```

There are any ideas why it happens? really strange..

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain your issue in more detail please?

Comment: I think you might have left off some of your question, this is a little unclear. Can you add anything to give us a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $.animate() multiple elements but only fire callback once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793246/jquery-animate-multiple-elements-but-only-fire-callback-once) -- the problem is that your `animate` callback is called once for each element, in this case `html` and `body`. Either use only `body` or the answer to that question. The problem might be with the other animation methods as well.

Comment: Simply there are two calls via the ajax, instead of one.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much, it works great, understood the problem. if you want, write it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `queue()`:

```
$('.simplebox').slideUp(200);
$('.simplebox').queue(function() {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:140}, 350);
    $('body').queue(function() {
        $('#loading-add').slideDown(300);
        $('#loading-add').queue(function() { 
            //ajax call
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: `$('body')` will suffice, it's similar though I update the code to reflect that.