# Run jQuery slideDown complete function only after last item has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that you can pass a function to slideUp/slideDown that will run once the transition has completed:

```
$('li').slideUp({
    complete: function(){
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

With this HTML an alert is shown 3 times.

```
<ul>
    <li>[content here]</li>
    <li>[content here]</li>
    <li>[content here]</li>
</ul>
```

Is there some way to have the `complete` function fire only once, when the *last* list item has completed the slideUp? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDYGJ/))

Comment: can't you slide up the UL?

Comment: I believe you'll have to target `li:last`

Comment: I could technically of course, but the effect is quite different @AndréPena

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793246/jquery-animate-multiple-elements-but-only-fire-callback-once

Comment: Wouldn't they all slide up at the same time?

Comment: @tymeJV However, I want *all* list items to slideUp. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Shawn31313 Yes they do, as the `duration` argument is the same for all list items. I'm looking for a way to run a function when they have all completed ("last one" may have been a poor choice of words).

Comment: Just use that same complete function as they will all be completed at the same time. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Shawn31313 -- The complete function fires 3 times, since each `li` runs its own complete function.

Comment: Oh okay. Now it makes sense. Ha.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can "redo" your selector and check if `this` is the last :

```
$('li').slideUp({
    complete: function(){
        if($('li:last').is(this)){
            alert('done');
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5NQsU/

Caching your selector would be even better :

```
var $li = $('li');
$li.slideUp({
    complete: function(){
        if($li.last().is(this)){
            alert('done');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `.is(this)`...damnit, I was trying to remember this, +1

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, will accept as soon as the system allows me. I suppose this would work just the same with `:first`, right? Since they all complete at the same time? I guess I could even have used a `isCompleted` flag or something now that I think of it...

Comment: @WesleyMurch It should work as well :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ultimate/KrW5a/

```
var total = $('ul').size();
var i = 1;
$('li').slideUp({
    complete: function () {
        if (i === total) alert('done');
        i += 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Karl's is better, just ignore this.