# Callbacks : animate complete: called after .promise().done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I made a very simple plugin for my personal use that allows animated rotations in jQuery.

And I added callback functions.

If the `rewind` parameter is `true`, the rotation is undone and then, a callback.

If it's `false`, the callback is immediate after the rotation.

I had to do this because, for some reason, the `.promise().done(function(){ ... })` is called before `complete:` of `animate()`

So I had to skirt this.

Now the problem is that if I target multiple elements, the callback is called for each element. 'cause I use an `each` function I presume. But I want only one callback for the whole animation.

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bhLtduom/)

How to do this please? Thx !

**PS:** I saw a similar question here : [jQuery $.animate() multiple elements but only fire callback once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793246/jquery-animate-multiple-elements-but-only-fire-callback-once) but not applying because of the `.promise().done()` issue. And I don't want to add a variable, I want to understand ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the index of `each` and only call the callback if it is the first element

Something like:

```
return this.each(function(i) {
   ....
   ....
   complete: function() {
        i==0 && a.callback &&  a.callback()
  }
```

Comment: Fastest and most efficient answer ever :) Thanks ! It works perfectly

Comment: I saw another place you call the callback. Not quite sure how it works there. Didn't look at it very long

Comment: I call it at two places, one if there is no rewind option, one if there is the rewind option. To avoid callback between the forward and backward animation.