# How to wait until hide effect is ended in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found few solution in here but non of them is the same as mine problems:

```
$('.listed-Item-Table').not(spesificItem).fadeTo('fast',0.2).hide(1000);
```

I got around 20 objects that are been hide.
After this hiding effect i ended i was to add some object into the `DOM` and show them.

while doing the following:

```
    $('.listed-Item-Table').not(spesificItem).fadeTo('fast',0.2).hide(1000 , 
      function(){
        addDetilsBox(spesificItem);
     });
```

I do add the object only after the hiding effect is done , but i'm adding him 20 times.

How should i wait until the hiding effect is over for all of the 20 items and only then add 1 object to the `DOM`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery, calling a callback only once after multiple animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432267/jquery-calling-a-callback-only-once-after-multiple-animations)

Comment: re the duplicate: in particular, be sure to check the alternative solution linked from there ([jQuery $.animate() multiple elements but only fire callback once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793246/jquery-animate-multiple-elements-but-only-fire-callback-once))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **[promise().done()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)** in jquery

```
$('.listed-Item-Table').not(spesificItem).fadeTo('fast',0.2).promise().done(function(){

// call back code
});
```